# How does Dictionary search a particular key value out of huge amount of data?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a very specific question about C hsarp Dictionary. 
Suppose you have 100000 Data in a Dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

And you have already filled up the dictionary using ...

```
 dictionary.Add("car", 1);
 dictionary.Add("apple", 2);
...
...
```

Now suppose you are searching a particular string in dictionary

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("apple"))
  {
     // then do this
  }
```

My question here is, How Dictionary search for this particualr value out of those many keys?
Is it going through linear Search. But msdn claims that dictionary searching complexity is close to O(1) [LinkMSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

What I know about Dictionary is that it doesn't have any internal search / sort algorithm.
[link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary)

Can anyone please explain how dictionary stored its values in memory and how does retrieving of the values happenned from system point of view. I know being a high level programmer we don't need to think about all these features of .Net but it is good to know. Actually I am curious to know. MSDN says it uses hashtable, but there is no explanation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: The Link is about hashTable wiki, but my question is how dictionary using hashtable so that searching of a particular string results O(1). How dictionary searching a particular string so fast?

Comment: It's important to note that "searching" a list doesn't necessarily imply any kind of "sort".

Comment: Even with a hash table, O(1) is a bit optimistic. It should be O(log N), shouldn't it?

Comment: @DanPuzey I mean searching and sort. It can be both at the same time or it can be only one.

Comment: @JohnB No, a good hash table implementation will have almost O(1) on average. That "almost" comes from additional cost which consists of: (1) obtaining the hash value from given key, (2) searching the exact key in the group of keys which map to the same hash value. With a good implementation for either this cost can be neglected.

Comment: You, however, have to look for the hash value within all stored hash values. Now assume your hash value is a 32 bit integer. If you use an array for storing the values associated with the hashes, the array must have 2^32 entries, in order to do the lookup by pointer arithmetic. That's too large. Hence you must do some kind of binary search, which brings you close to O(log N). You can achieve O(1) only if you have unlimited memory.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. I should have read the Wiki article before.

Answer (score 2):

From the same [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) in your question you can see:

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1),
>   because the Dictionary class is implemented as a **hash
>   table**.

I believe you need to read about hash table.

Probably a good starting point would be:  [Hash Tables - Data Structures](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/hash_tables.html)

Comment: Is that the only answer that using hashtable, dictionary searching a particular digit or string and throw the result to the user. is that so fast?

Comment: @Debhere, you may see the article about hash tables, linked in the answer

Comment: @Debhere: a Hashtable is a data structure that is specifically designed to give very fast lookups of values, close to O(1).  So yes, that is so fast :-)

Comment: @Habib: this is a question and answer site.  Instead of repeatedly linked off to other content, try to give a useful overview of what you're linking to, so that the question-asker has an idea of what you're saying.  The page you link to is long, complex, and non-obvious: this site exists (in part) to counterbalance that somewhat.

Comment: @Habib yes I am going through that article. thanks for sharing the article.

Comment: It would be better if anybody can explain the internal mechanism. That is what I was expected. Anyhow thanks for the sharing.

Comment: @DanPuzey O(1) infers scalability. Not performance. If each hash takes 10 billion CPU ticks it is still O(1) but in reality the performance is garbage. So the hash implementation is crucial to the answer the OP is asking.